# The specified assets destination folder ios does not exist React native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to run react active iOS and I am getting following error

```
npx react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios && yarn ios
```

[The specified assets destination folder ios does not exist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGouY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved by

```
npx react-native bundle --entry-file ./index.js --platform ios --bundle-output ./ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest packages/mobile/ios && yarn ios
```